# How do I make it only allow users to enter text channels, not categories, voice channels...all allow users to enter?

Tags: python, pycord

```py
import discord

from discord.ext import commands

from discord.commands import Option

import json

def create_server_data(server_ID,channel_ID,text_detection):

    server_data={

        server_ID:{

            "Channel id":channel_ID,

            "Now number":0,

            "High number":0,

            "text_detection":text_detection

        }

   },

    return server_data

  

def write_to_json(data):

    with open("data/fun/number_solitaire.json","w", encoding="UTF-8") as f:

        json.dump(data, f, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)

class Number_Solitaire_Command(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):

        self.bot = bot

    @discord.slash_command(name="add_number_solitaire",description="管理員|新增數字接龍頻道")

    async def add_number_solitaire(

        self,

        ctx,

        channel:Option(discord.abc.GuildChannel,"輸入要玩數字接龍的頻道"),

          text_detection:Option(str,"是否偵測訊息是否是數字，若輸入“是”，則可以在該頻道內聊天，若輸入“否”，則若是文字則會被判定為輸入錯誤",choices=["是","否"],default="否")

                ):

        channel_ID=channel.id

        server_ID=ctx.guild.id

        message=None

        if text_detection=="是":

            message=True

        elif text_detection=="否":

            message=False

        write_to_json(create_server_data(server_ID,channel_ID,message))

        

        embed = discord.Embed(

            title="數字接龍頻道綁定成功",

            color=discord.Colour.random(),

                             )

        embed.add_field(name="伺服器ID"

                        ,value=server_ID,inline=True

                       )

        embed.add_field(name="頻道ID",value=channel_ID,inline=True)

        embed.add_field(name="頻道連結",value=f"https://discord.com/channels/{server_ID}/{channel_ID}",inline=True)

        embed.add_field(name="是否偵測訊息為數字",value=text_detection,inline=True)

        embed.set_footer(text="/add_number_solitaire")

        embed.set_author(name=ctx.user.name,icon_url=ctx.user.avatar.url)

        embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.bot.user.avatar.url)

        await ctx.respond(embed=embed,ephemeral=message)

def setup(bot):

    bot.add_cog(Number_Solitaire_Command(bot))
```

This is my pycord code. I want to know how to only allow users to enter text channels in `channel` instead of voice channels, categories... If possible, I hope to provide a more concise one. Because of the current code, I still think it can be shorter, but I have no clue.

I expect that only the text channel will appear in the channel option section.